# how can I get last echoed message in vimscript?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to retrieve last echoed message into a variable?
For example: if i call function, that does:

```
echo 'foo'
```

Can I somehow retrieve this 'foo' into a variable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't retrieve last echoed message. But there are other options:

1. If you can place a `:redir` command before this function call and another one after, you can catch everything it echoes. But be aware that redirections do not nest, so if function uses `:redir` itself, you may get nothing:

   ```
   redir => s:messages
   echo "foo"
   redir END
   let s:lastmsg=get(split(s:messages, "\n"), -1, "")
   ```
2. If function uses `:echomsg` instead of `:echo`, then you can use `:messages` command and `:redir`:

   ```
   echom "foo"
   redir => s:messages
   messages
   redir END
   let s:lastmsg=get(split(s:messages, "\n"), -1, "")
   ```

Comment: You can also change it to `1messages` to get only the most recent one